Is this a sufficient condition to interchange infinite sums?
I came across this wikipedia article, which has the following result:

Theorem 5: If $a_{m,n}$ is a sequence and $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_{m,n}$ exists uniformly in $m$, and $\lim_{m \to \infty} a_{m,n}$ exists, then the iterated limits exist and are independent of order.

The article then claims that a direct corollary is

If $\sum^\infty_{n=1} a_{n,m}$ converges uniformly in $m$, and $\sum^\infty_{m =1} a_{n,m}$ converges for each $n$, then  $\sum^\infty_{m=1} \sum^\infty_{n=1} a_{n,m} = \sum^\infty_{n=1} \sum^\infty_{m=1} a_{n,m}.$

However, I noticed that to apply Theorem 5 what I really need is the convergence of the iterated partial sums $\lim_{k \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^k\sum_{m=1}^la_{m,n}$ uniformly in $l$, which I understand to be different than the sum $\sum^\infty_{n=1} a_{n,m}$ to converge uniformly in $m$ (and perhaps is what the author intended to write after all).
My question is if the corollary is correct as stated? I tried both proving the statement and finding a counterexample, but both to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
